# Can't implement google sign in with Firebase in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am a beginner and I trying to implement google sign into my project.
I have tried different approaches found on google, but none of them worked.

On this line `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider` the `'auth'` with an error:

> Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/.../").

And on imports `import { auth } from 'firebase/auth';` the error is on `{ auth }` with the error:

> 'auth' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
> '"firebase/auth"' has no exported member named 'auth'. Did you mean 'Auth'?

The `//` commented lines on `import` are different versions I have tried

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/auth';
// import { firebase } from 'firebase/app'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat';
// import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  login() {
    this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Errors? Please be specific and provide [mre]

Comment: Yes, errors. Especially on auth. I put a picture with the code showing the errors. Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof 
On import 'auth' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: Then, you have to post the error message. Please refer to [mre]

Comment: Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof
(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider)

Comment: Please lookup in SO, there a ton of similar questions

Comment: I'm stuck since yesterday, and I have looked everywhere, even on SO, but I keep getting errors. That's why I put up this question. Because I tried different methods, and they don’t work.